# Set a maximum step size in odeint

Tags: boost, numerical-integration, odeint

I create a boost::odeint stepper as follows:

```
auto stepper=boost::numeric::odeint::make_dense_output(0.01/*Absolute*/,0.1/*Relative*/, boost::numeric::odeint::runge_kutta_dopri5< CombinedState >() );
```

There will be times during the integration of my system where it "lies low" for a while. During this periods it seems as though the integrator sometimes increases its step size to the point where it then jumps over areas of interest.

Is there a way to limit the integrator's step size so it never exceeds a given maximum?

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry, but this is not possible at the moment. Nevertheless, if this feature is really important for you, just copy the controlled_runge_kutta to a stepper with a different name like max_dt_controlled_runge_kutta and insert a check for the maximal time-step by hand. The code is not too complicated. You only have to do it twice, since there exist two specializations of controlled_runge_kutta.

If there are problems just let me know.

Comment: Do you mean that the try_step() functions in the class controlled_runte_kutta should fail if dt > dt_max? And what do you mean by doing it twice? Would it be enough to change the class declaration? Why would I have to touch the specializations?

Comment: Yes, the try_step() should fail if dt > dt_max. By twice I mean that there exist two specializations of controlled_runge_kutta, one for  "classical" steppers, like cash_karp and one for fsal like dopri5 steppers. But you are right, maybe one class is enough and can work for both specializations.